# Is it possible to upgrade from El Capitan to Sierra if you have the pkg and pfpkg files?

Tags: macos

Per [this article](https://7labs.heypub.com/tips-tricks/macos-sierra-direct-download.html) I downloaded the 10.12.6 versions of Sierra's pkg and pfpkg files. I cannot use the technique described in the article because Sierra is no longer available in the App Store. Is there a way to use these files to upgrade my MBP without the App Store?

Comment: I may be missing something, but it looks to me like the 10.12.6 combo update is still up on the Apple site:
https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1931?locale=en_US

Combo update should still work, no?

Comment: What I downloaded is not the combo update; it's the Sierra installation package referred to in the linked article.

Comment: Just checked on mine...Not perfect but possible solution if you can get your hands on a machine that does have Sierra installed.
 
I upgraded this one from 10.11.something to 10.12 and I have the "Install macOS Sierra.app" in my Applications. The regular installESD.dmg is inside of that, and I'm betting the .pkg's you're looking for are in there...

Answer (score 2):

Only if you know the exact location of the files for 10.12.6, the last available version.

From your link...

> Update: Here, we have mentioned the URL of the package file for macOS
>   10.12. If the latest version of macOS Sierra available on the Mac App Store is a different one, MAS will fetch it from a different location.
>   Hence the workaround mentioned here will not work, unless you know the
>   URL of the latest package file and create the directory structure on
>   localhost based on the same.

It's always wisest to download any major new version from the App Store - any time between when it's released & when it's taken down - even if you never install it. That way it will always be in your purchase history & you can get it again at any time.

Comment: Good advice.  I hope I adhere to it in the future. What's disconcerting in this case is I've seen forums posts from yesterday and today where people had "purchased" the Sierra download and used it, yet now it does not show up in their App Store "Purchased" list. One local acquaintance said he cannot find Sierra in his Purchased list. Maybe these are anomalies.

Comment: Intersting - Sierra is missing from my Purchased list too,. though the public beta is there. I always like belt & braces though... I have all the installers back to Lion backed up here ;)

Comment: [This article](https://www.macrumors.com/2017/09/26/macos-sierra-decoupled-from-apple-id/) and [this article](https://512pixels.net/2017/09/macos-sierra-removed-from-mac-app-store/) elaborate on and confirm that Sierra is no longer available under Purchased.

Answer (score 1):

Why not ask a friend that has Sierra in his Purchased list, to download it, and give you the installer file that comes in his Applications folder. You can use that to install Sierra.